Openshift Deployment giving 503 error while hitting the URL
i have a spring boot app trying to deploy in openshift, but giving the 503 error app is running on port 8080.. here are the configs i have used for the deployment
pipeline
Stages:
    -deploy:container
    -deploy:service
    -deploy:route


deploy: container:
    extends: init
    stage: deploy: app 
    script:
        - oc apply -f $(PROJECT_DIR}/crdeployment.yml -n $CR_PROJECT

deploy: service:
    extends: init
    stage: deploy: service
    script:
        - oc apply -f ${PROJECT_DIR}/cr/service.ymL -n $CR_PROJECT
    when: on_success dependencies:
        - deploy: container

deploy: route:
    extends: init
    stage: deploy:route 
    script:
        - oc apply -f $(PROJECT_DIR}/cr/route.yml -n $CR_PROJECT
        - appUrl=oc get route ${CR_LABEL} -n $(CR_PROJECT} -template='https://{{.spec.host}]"
        - echo "App URL ${appUrl}"
    when: on_success
     dependencies:
        - deploy:service

Route.yml
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route 
metadata:
    name: demo-world
    namespace: demp
    labels:
        app: demo-world 
spec:
    path: / 
    to:
        kind: Service 
        name: demo-world
    port:
        targetPort: 8080
    tls:
        termination: edge
        insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
        wildcardPolicy: None 
status:
    ingress:
        - host: demo-world.apps.ocp-test.tnet.com
           routerName: default 
           conditions:
            - type: Admitted
               status: "True'
          wildcardPolicy: None
             routerCanonicalHostname: apps.ocp-test.tnet.com

Deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
Kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: demo-world 
    namespace:demp
    labels:
        app: demo-world
spec:
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: demo-world
    replicas: 3 
    template:
        metadata: 
            labels:
                app: demo-world 
    spec:
        containers:
            - name: demo-world
               image: demo-world-dev-Local.artifactory.tnet.com/demo-world:113
              resources:
                Limiits:
                    memory: 256Mi 
                    cpu: 200m
                requests:
                    memory: 128Mi
                    cpu: 180m
            ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate 
    rollingUpdate:
        maxUnavailable: 1
        masSurge: 1

Service.yml
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata:
    name: demo-world 
    namespace: demp
    labels:
        app: demo-world
spec:
    selector:
        app: demo-world
    ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 80
           targetPort: 8080

I'm not sure what's the issue or I'm missed something while exposing the ports.. can any one help me.. thanks in advance

Try adding livenessProbe to Deployment.yml something like this after ports inside spec section - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#:~:text=healthy%3B%20sleep%20600-,livenessProbe%3A,-exec%3A

tried but its not working showing the same 503 when we open the link
